# Looking for exact cause and resolution of : java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, sockets

The exception is thrown using Apache FTPClient in `LOCAL_PASSIVE_MODE`. The process is running from a PC in a remote site over a satellite connection which I know to be less than stable. The same code works flawlessly over a stable connection to the same server, but I'm not sure if the difference comes from the stability of the connection, or the speed (ie, server configured timeouts)

My questions are as follows :

- Is it necessarily the case that the connection was closed by the remote host (as stated in the exception), or is it possible that an interupted internet connection will generate the same exception ?
- If it is true that an interupted internet connection will cause this exception how can I parameterize the FTPClient, or the underlying Socket to retry and resume the connection ?
- How can I test if the connection was closed by the remote server or interupted ?

The FTPClient is configured for :

- Connection timeout : 10 minutes
- Data timeout : 10 minutes
- Keep alive : enabled
- Keep alive signals sent every 10 seconds
- Keep alive reply from server timeout : 10 minutes
- FTP buffer size : 1024 x 1024

I am waiting to receive the server configuration file and the server logs.

The stack trace is as follows :

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) 
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:317) 
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:45) 
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683) 
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:659) 
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:648) 
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68) 
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1120) 
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessarily the case that the connection was closed by the remote host (as stated in the exception), or is it possible that an interupted internet connection will generate the same exception?

No. The localhost received an RST from the peer. If the Internet connection was interrupted this would cause the local TCP to abort the connection, eventually, with a different message, such as 'software caused connection abort' or 'the connection was aborted by the software in your local host', whatever the exact wording is on your system. If it says 'by the remote host', it means it.

> If it is true that an interupted internet connection will cause this exception

It isn't.

> how can I parameterize the FTPClient, or the underlying Socket to retry and resume the connection?

I can't answer for the FTPClient, but a `Socket` that has had this exception is dead and must be closed. It cannot retry anything.

It would be more to the point to examine *why* the peer aborted the connection. For example, you may be violating an upload-size limit.

> How can I test if the connection was closed by the remote server or interrupted?

Via the error message, unfortunately. They could have mapped the various `errno` values that can arise in sockets to different `IOException` or indeed `SocketException` subclasses, but they only did so in a few cases, such as `ConnectException`, `SocketTimeoutException`, ...